# Overlapping text on mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I have a mobile view issue on bootstrap wherein the texts overlap the next section
[image]

The smallest media query I have is 768px and the screen that I'm checking is from an iPhone XS Max

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .services .carousel-inner p{
    margin-top: 110px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px){
    .services .carousel-item p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 120px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .services .carousel-item p{
    width: 60%;
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi){
    .services .carousel-item p{
    margin-top: 105px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
@media
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
(min-resolution: 120dpi), (max-resolution: 125dpi){
    .services .carousel-item p{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

What can I improve on to fix my issue?

Comment: Can you give us an example with html and css? also what other css applies to the element. I assume you either set a height specifically on a container element or you have some negative margins somewhere.

Comment: @StefanF. here's the html. There are no negative margins anywhere on my code and I use bootstrap 4 on this site https://pastebin.com/bCbhd8dp

Comment: @Highcenburg `.services` is not existing in your html code

Comment: @DohaHelmy it does

Comment: based on the link you provided, I am sure it is not. Anyway, probably you apply a fixed `height` to your carousel which makes your content overlapp when its height is higher than the predefined `height`. If this is the case use `min-height` instead

Comment: Check its parent, it must have `height:100vh` due to which this happens

Answer (score 0):

```
.services{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5;
}
.services .carousel-inner{
    height: 100%;
}
```